# Java replace invisible chaaracters

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

There are invisible consecutive dots (..) in a text string. I can only see them if I view the file as a binary. If I open it with Vim, I cannot see them. These dots mess up further parsing and I would like to replace these hidden dots. Would

```
 replaceAll("\\.","dot")
```

work on invisible characters?

Update: Hex Dump for 'ATA ..Buffer' is 41 54 41 20 20 20 20 09 09 42 75 66 66 65 72 20
I think the 09 are the hex values for the 'dots'

Comment: It is always better to read a binary file in bytes and not as a String directly. Later you can convert the bytes into a String

Comment: You need to find out what those characters *actually* are. They're clearly *not* dots, as dots are visible. Please post a hex dump of the relevant section of the file, and tell us what encoding you're using.

Comment: I don't think they are `dots`, I think they are no printable characters.  What are there hex values?

Comment: @Ankur: It may well actually be a text file, with some control characters. If it's *not* text, then yes, it should be read as bytes - but if it *is* a text file, there's no need to keep it just as binary data.

Comment: @Ankur: I'm not sure what you mean. The original data is in sequence snappy format that I read with map reduce java. Output is in text that has this problem. Do you mean I should read the line as BytesWritrable? (Not sure how to convert this to string though for manipulation)

Comment: @JonSkeet :Err, how do I find the hex values and the encoding? The file is in text format.

Comment: @user2441441: You should *know* the encoding - we can't tell you it. It will depend on whatever wrote the file. As for the hex values - whatever you were using to "view the file as binary" should be showing you that.

Comment: Okay. Hex dump for part of the string 'ATA ..Buffer' is: 
0000300:   41 54 41 20 20 20 20 09 09 42 75 66 66 65 72 20. If you want I have more hex dumps. I think the dots are 09.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think that the encoding of the input file is UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
41 54 41 20 20 20 20 09 09 42 75 66 66 65 72 20
```

Assuming plain ASCII (which is in this case the same as assuming UTF-8), as a Java string, this is

```
"ATA    \t\tBuffer "
```

Note that `\t` stands for the horizontal tab character.

Comment: Its 'ATA ..Buffer ' . Yes, there are about two tabs between ATA and Buffer, but in the above comment there is a '*K' instead of Bu? I don't think it is in UTF-8 then (Someone else wrote the file) Another Hex dump example is for 'Size \= 4000 ..' it is: 53 69 7a 65 20 20 5c 3d 20 34 30 30 30 20 09 09

Comment: I tried it in this website that converts hex to string, it converts it correctly. The link is http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx So it might be in UTF-8 after all.

Comment: No, sorry, I've looked up two chars in the wrong column. But the point is that the invisible chars are nothing but tabs. UTF-8 is indistinguishable from ASCII for the range below hex 80.

Comment: So, I'm not sure what I need to do. I can see them as dots when its viewed as binary(and tabs when it is viewed text) and their hex values are 09. Should I remove the tabs in the string? something like replaceAall("\\\t\\\t","  ")?

Comment: Well, what's your goal? The hex 09 tab character is a very common, tame character and in most cases it doesn't interfere with anything. Do whatever is appropriate for your case. BTW replacing is best done with `string.replace('\t',' ')`, not `replaceAll`, which takes a regex.

Comment: Okay. So the goal is to load the output file in a Hive table and for some reason whenever Hive encounters the hex 09 tab character, it breaks the string and puts it in the next column (when it should put it in the same column).

Comment: That sounds like Hive interprets the string as tab-delimited values. Then it's best to replace tab with space.

Comment: PS: does replace() throw a Null Pointer exception if the tabs are not found? If it does I would like it to ignore it and go to the next code line.

Comment: It doesn't. It replaces any and all characters.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following two methods, toPrintable to convert the original string to a printable string, fromPrintable to convert it back.

I included the percent sign in the conversion because sometimes I may want to use the converted string as a part of a format string and this prevents the original percent signs getting confused with the formatting percent signs.

```
/**
 * Converts a string containing control characters to a printable string.
 * Control characters are replaced by \hh, were hh is the hexadecimal
 * representation. The backslash and percent sign are also converted to
 * hexadecimal.
 * 
 * @param raw
 *            The input string to be converted.
 * 
 * @return a string representing this instance.
 */
public static String toPrintable(final String raw) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (raw == null) {
        return "";
    }

    for (final char c : raw.toCharArray()) {
        if ((c <= 31) || (c == 127) || (c == '\\') || (c == '%')) {
            sb.append(String.format("\\%02X", (int) c));
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    /*
     * If the last character is a space, convert it to hexadecimal, to avoid
     * loosing it.
     */
    if (raw.endsWith(" ")) {
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append("\\20");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Converts a string containing coded control characters to the original
 * string. Control characters are represented by \hh, were hh is the
 * hexadecimal representation. The backslash is also represented as
 * hexadecimal.
 * 
 * @param t
 *            The converted string to be restored.
 * @return The original string.
 */
public static String fromPrintable(final String t) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    final int tLength = t.length();
    boolean error = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < tLength; i++) {
        if (t.charAt(i) == '\\') {
            if ((i + 1) < tLength) {
                if (t.charAt(i + 1) == '\\') {
                    sb.append(t.charAt(i++));
                } else {
                    if (i < (tLength - 2)) {
                        final int v1 = validHexDigits.indexOf(t
                                .charAt(i + 1));
                        final int v2 = validHexDigits.indexOf(t
                                .charAt(i + 2));
                        i += 2;
                        if ((v1 < 0) || (v2 < 0)) {
                            error = true;
                        } else {
                            final char cc = (char) ((validHexValues[v1] << 4) + validHexValues[v2]);
                            sb.append(cc);
                        }
                    } else {
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                error = true;
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(t.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    if (error) {
        log.warn("fromPrintable: Invalid input [%s]", t);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```